# The python command-line file handling doesn't work? am i working correctly?

Tags: python, command-line, ubuntu-12.04

I am a new python learner and now i have entered into file handling.

I tried solution for my problem but failed, so posting my question. before duplication please consider my question.

I tried to create a file, it worked.
writing in the file also worked.

But when i tried to read the text or values in the file, it returns empty.

I use command line terminal to work with python and running in Ubuntu OS.

The coding which I have tried is given below. The file is created in the desired location and the written text is also present.

```
f0=open("filehandling.txt","wb")
f0.write("my second attempt")
s=f0.read(10);
print s
```

I also tried with wb+, r+. But it just returns as empty

edit 1:

I have attached the coding below. I entered one by one in command line

```
fo = open("samp.txt", "wb")
fo.write( "Text is here\n");

fo.close()

fo = open("samp.txt", "r+")
str = fo.read(10);

print "Read String is : ", str

fo.close()
```

Comment: Works for me (on Python 3) when I don't open the file in binary mode (`fo = open("samp.txt", "w")`). Should work in Python 2 as it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all if you `open` with `wb` flag then the file will be only in writeable mode. If you want to both read and write then you need `wb+` flag. If you don't want the file to be truncated each time then you need `rb+`.

Now files are streams with pointers pointing at a certain location inside the file. If you write

```
f0.write("my second attempt")
```

then the pointer points at the `[pointer before writing]` (in your case the begining of the file, i.e. `0`) plus `[length of written bytes]` (in your case `17`, which is the end of the file). In order to read whole file you have to move that pointer back to the begining and then read:

```
f0.seek(0)
data = f0.read()
```

Comment: I also tried with r+ after creation sorry that i forgot to mention it

Comment: @anandmbs Have you read my answer until the end? It returns empty because you read from the end of the file. You need `f0.seek(0)`.

Comment: thank you @freakish. I closed the file and reopened it. So by default, the pointer must go to the initial position when we open in r+ mode right? Then why did i get an empty string?

Comment: @anandmbs: In that case you might want to edit your question to show the real code you used.

Comment: @anandmbs Show us **exactly** what you are doing, step by step, line by line. From what you are saying the behaviour is simply impossible.